# How react-router-redux pass initial state?

Tags: redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

With react-router-redux, I have the Code:

```
const reducers = combineReducers({
  ...counterReducer,
  routing: routerReducer
})

const store = createStore(reducers, {initialState: 10})
const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store)

console.log(store.getState())
```

The output like:

[image]

why I don't get the {initialState: 10} in the state ?

Comment: Do any of your reducers handle `initialState`?

Comment: Before the console.log, I have't dispatch any action, so no reducer has deal with it.

Comment: In https://github.com/wd4blue/react-redux/blob/dev/src/app/index.jsx , the comment code is react-router, it works fine without redux. But I don't know how to combine the react-router-redux with redux. And I need pass the initial state.

Comment: I have got it, my combineReducers include method wrong. Many thanks.